# Update and print a number, exponentially

Tags: c, algorithm

My problem is find a way to reduce the number of updateAccelerometer calls.

```
int count = 0;
int accelerometer = updateAccelerometer();
while (accelerometer <= 500) {
  printf("Actual: %lf", accelerometer);
  accelerometer = updateAccelerometer();
  count++;
}
```

Which gives:

```
Actual: 9
Actual: 28
Actual: 47
Actual: 65
Actual: 84
Actual: 103
Actual: 122
Actual: 141
Actual: 159
Actual: 178
Actual: 197
Actual: 216
Actual: 235
Actual: 253
Actual: 272
Actual: 291
Actual: 310
Actual: 329
Actual: 347
Actual: 366
Actual: 385
Actual: 404
Actual: 423
Actual: 442
Actual: 460
Actual: 479
Actual: 498
```

Now my problem is that **I dont want to update the accelerometer every time**, but in an exponential proportional ratio, for example. If I introduce a "linear proportional ratio"

I will just do:

```
if (count % 2 = 0) accelerometer = updateAccelerometer();
```

Which means, one value will be read, one value will not be, etc etc etc, since everytime I call updateAccelerometer it might take time, I would like to take less values when I am far away and more value when I am closer.

So the idea is to have an exponential function that will return me only the ones marked with x, **not because I dont print the others, but because I dont update the accelerometer**

```
Actual: 9
Actual: 28
Actual: 47
Actual: 65
Actual: 84
Actual: 103x
Actual: 122
Actual: 141
Actual: 159
Actual: 178
Actual: 197
Actual: 216
Actual: 235x
Actual: 253
Actual: 272
Actual: 291
Actual: 310
Actual: 329x
Actual: 347
Actual: 366
Actual: 385
Actual: 404x
Actual: 423
Actual: 442
Actual: 460x
Actual: 479
Actual: 498x
```

This is not a very specific problem, since I had this problem of exponentially skipping updates in many other situation, any tick?

Comment: Values 6,12,17,21,24,26 are not exponential. They are some kind of logarithmic function.

Comment: The code shown passes the `int` `accelerometer` where `printf` expects a `double` to match the `%lf` specifier. This is incorrect and is not expected to work. It is unlikely the output shown is produced by the code shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the number of counts until you next sample the accelerator should be about `sqrt(fabs(500 - accelerometer)) / 3.25`.

Comment: will this work if one day I implement a faster or a slower accelerator ? how did you derive that 3.25 ?

Comment: anyway, the number of counts is not proportional to the accelerometer

Comment: @haskellguy: I just worked backwards, fitting a curve to your data.  And it's not proportional to the accelerometer; the *difference* in counts is proportional to (a power of) how far away the accelerometer is from its target value.  In this case the power 0.5 seemed to fit your desired curve.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. But now, the implementation would be writing `if (sqrt(fabs(500 - accelerometer)) / 3.25 == ????) update&print`

Comment: @haskellguy: The `== ????` would be `<= count - last_update_count`, and you'd set `last_update_count = count;` when you do the update.

Comment: @haskellguy: Alternatively you could just store the accelerometer value at the last update, then do something like `if ((accelerometer - last_accelerometer) / (target_value - last_accelerometer) > 0.5) { }` (as long as you can read the accelerometer without updating it - that much is not clear).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you can do it! Set with predefined iteration indexes when the data should be printed, some kind of mathematical function to determine it.

I however would go with something like this:

```
int count = 0;
int timeToPrint = 5;
int timeSincePrinted = 0;
int minPrintSpan = 2;
int accelerometer = updateAccelerometer();
while (accelerometer <= 500) {
  timeSincePrinted++;
  if (timeToPrint == timeSincePrinted && timeSincePrinted >= minPrintSpan) {
    printf("Actual: %lf and %d", accelerometer, count);
    timeSincePrinted=0;
    timeToPrint--;
  }
  accelerometer = updateAccelerometer();
  count++;
}
```

That wat you have a fairly simple, low-complexity and easily tunable functionality. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is cool, but probably I express wrongly the idea. I want to print  & updateAccelerometer() exponentially (given that I can predict the linear increase of the accelerometer). I think a quick fix would be to include accelerometer in the if statement, however, this will not be dependent from the accelerometer counting